# Is it possible to include different content for different social media using UIActivityViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, facebook-social-plugins

I am using MobileCoreServices of ios 7 to post content from app to social media. . And here is my code ..

```
NSArray *activityItems;

NSString *title =  _titleLabel.text;

if (_imageLabel.image != nil) {
    activityItems = @[title, _imageLabel.image];
} else {
    activityItems = @[title];
}

UIActivityViewController *activityController =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc]
 initWithActivityItems:activityItems
 applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:activityController

    animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now it sends common text. I wish to post different titles for Facebook and twitter. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You need to subclass UIActivityItemProvider

   ```
   @interface APCustomActivityProvider : UIActivityItemProvider <UIActivityItemSource>
   @end
   ```
2. Add the following to your implementation file

   ```
   @implementation APCustomActivityProvider
   - (id) activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController
     itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
   {
     if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToTwitter] ){
       NSString *title = @"Twitter title";
       return title;
     }
     if ( [activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypePostToFacebook] ) {
       NSString *title = @"Facebook title";
       return title;
     }
     return nil;
   }

   - (id) activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController*)activityViewController { return @""; }
   @end
   ```
3. To use your custom ActivityProvider, go to where you are presenting your UIActivityViewController

   ```
   NSArray *activityItems;
   APCustomActivityProvider *activityProvider = [[APCustomActivityProvider alloc] init];
   if (_imageLabel.image != nil) {
       activityItems = @[activityProvider, _imageLabel.image];
   } else {
       activityItems = @[activityProvider];
   }


   UIActivityViewController *activityController = 
   [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems   
                                     applicationActivities:nil];

   [self presentViewController:activityController
                      animated:YES completion:nil];
   ```

Comment: This helped me more than the webpage did, so thanks!

Comment: The tutorial link is broken